# Passing my payload through JSON.parse alters my date object values to not line up

Tags: javascript, json, date

Prior to using `JSON.parse()`, my payload contents are as follows:

```
let payload = {
     "name":"bob",
     "timeDetails":
        [
            {
                "windowName":"Window A",
                "windowTimes":
                    {
                        "startDate":"2021-11-20T20:39:46.785Z",
                        "endDate":"2021-11-20T20:39:54.786Z"
                    }
            }
        ]
    }
```

So paying particular attention to my dates, when I then proceed to issue the following on the above payload, i.e.:

```
let job = JSON.parse(payload);
console.log(job);
```

I am now getting the following `startDate` and `endDate` returned which is not the same as my original payload dates, i.e. from my console log:

```
startDate: Sun Nov 21 2021 16:00:00 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time) {}
endDate: Sun Nov 21 2021 23:00:00 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time) {}
```

I am not so much concerned about the time portion but I would've thought I would've seen the dates as: `Sat Nov 20 2021` for both startDate/endDate?

Can someone help with what I am missing as need to ensure that dates are like for like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking date string as UTC Time zone ("2021-11-20T20:39:46.785Z", UTC format).
It adds 11 (GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time) hours to UTC time, so adding 11 hours to Nov 20 gets Nov 21 as a result
If you want to get the Exact UTC zone we have to convert it to UTC format

Comment: Are you able to please assist on what the UTC format needs to be in order to for me to achieve `Exact UTC zone` that is, like for like with the Nov 20? I am not too familiar with how to achieve this.

Comment: Have to convert date string to UTC then convert date to UTC like (new Date("2021-11-20T20:39:46.785Z")).toUTCString()